# Prevent redirect to wp-login.php

Tags: php, html, authentication

So I have made a separate **login page** for my Wordpress site.
When I log in I just go to the home page like how I want it to.
But when I click **forgot password** and fill in my mail it redirects to `wp-login.php`

And if I change the redirect to `/login/` the mails for **resetting the password** is not sent out anymore

The code for the form on the forgot password page is as follows:

```
<form name="lostpasswordform" id="lostpasswordform" class="lostpasswordform" action="<?= site_url("/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword") ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="" size="20" placeholder="Email" required />
    <a class="forgot" href="/login/">Inloggen</a>
    <input name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Wachtwoord resetten" />
</form>
```

But when I change the redirect to:

```
action="<?= site_url("/login?action=lostpassword") ?>"
```

It does redirect me to the login page as I want it to.
But now like I said before the mail isn't sent out any more.

How can I make it so it still redirects to `/login/`
and also still sends out the mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't have code on your new login form that supports `?action=lostpassword` ?

Your choices are either

1. copy the relevant code from wp-login.php to your new form; you want the retrieve_password() function. Then you can post back to `/login?action=lostpassword`.
2. use your own 'lost password' form, but post to `/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword`

   1. hook the [lostpassword_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/lostpassword_redirect/) filter to choose where to redirect to after a successful reset
   2. hook the [lostpassword_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/lostpassword_url/) filter to point to your form, so that it'll redirect there on errors
3. rather than add a new form, use the default wp-login form instead but with your own styling?